# Brain storming about some jQuery if statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have three if statements. I need another if statement which is related with these three like this: 
If (these three if statements return true) {
ajax send
} else { 
do not send
}. 
Also If you guys want to say your recommendations about my codes I'll be greatful.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#name").focusout(function() {
        var name = $('#name').val();
        name = $.trim(name);

        if (name == '') {
            $('#arrow_box1').css({
                "visibility": "visible"
            });
        } else {
            $('#box1').css({
                "visibility": "hidden"
            });
        }
    }); 

    $("#email").focusout(function() {
        var email = $('#email').val();
        email = $.trim(email);

        var validateEmail = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+/;

        if (email == '' || !validateEmail.test(email)) {
            $('#box2').css({
                "visibility": "visible"
            });
        } else {
            $('#box2').css({
                "visibility": "hidden"
            });
        }
    });

    $("#password").focusout(function() {

        var password = $('#password').val();
        password = $.trim(password);
        var passlength = password.length;       

        if (password == '' || passlength < 6) {
            $('#box3').css({
                "visibility": "visible"
            });
        } else {
            $('#box3').css({
                "visibility": "hidden"
            });
        }
    });

        $('#submit-btn').click(function(){

            var loginform = $('#register-form').serialize();

                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax/ajaxregister.php",
                    data: $('#register-form').serialize(),
                    success: function(c) {
                        if(c == "ok") {
                            window.location.href = "homepage.php";
                        } else {
                           alert('log in failed!');
                        }
                    }
                 });            
        });
});
```

Comment: What three if-statements are you referring to?  Each `if` in the `focusout` event handlers?

Comment: How can I reach there different inputs(name, email, password) with only one if statement?

Comment: Just use jQuery to access each of them: `$("#name").val()`, `$("#email").val()`, and `$("#password").val()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a validator cache after document ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var vaildator = {
        isNameError: undefined,
        isEmailError: undefined,
        isPasswordError: undefined
    };
```

Then, set them to `true` or `false` in your three if statements.

```
if (name == '') {
    vaildator.isNameError = true;
    $('#arrow_box1').css({
        "visibility": "visible"
    });
} else {
    vaildator.isNameError = false;
    $('#box1').css({
        "visibility": "hidden"
    });
}
```

Finally, add if before your ajax call

```
if (vaildator.isNameError === false && 
    vaildator.isEmailError === false &&
    vaildator.isPasswordError === false) {
    $.ajax({
```